# Building YQL Open Data Tables for Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, yql

i have been scouring the web researching the possibility of sourcing an implementation of the Facebook newest graph api open data table for YQL and i haven't seen any....

is it possible to implement a yQL open table for Facebook's newest graph api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to implement a YQL Open Table for Facebook's newest graph api.
But first you have to make sure that a straightforward api already exists for that, then you will be able to create a YQL Open Table. 
You can use the [YQL Editor](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/editor/) which for me is the easiest way to create a YQL Open Table.

Have fun buddy

Comment: Thanks man...was wondering why someone hadn't done it already!